# Get Members Who Did Not Place Order in Join Query and count their Commission

Tags: php, join, codeigniter-3

I am working on project, where marketers place order. And Marketer can also join the website by someone who refer him.

One user is **referee (628)** and 2nd user is **referrer (474)**.

Now **marketer (628)** places 4 orders and **marketer (474)** did not place any order.

Now I am counting commission like this in Model function.

```
function getbuyerscommision()
{

    $date_from = strtotime(date("Y-n-j", strtotime("first day of previous month")) . '+18 hours +59 minutes 59 seconds');
    $date_to = strtotime(date("Y-n-j", strtotime("last day of previous month")) . '+18 hours +59 minutes 59 seconds');



    $this->db->select('mt.*, ot.* ,SUM(ot.product_commision) as totalcomm , count(ot.id) as totalorders');
    $this->db->from('orders ot');
    $this->db->join('members mt', 'mt.id = ot.buyer_id');

    $this->db->group_start();
    $this->db->where(array('ot.status' => 'refunded'));
    $this->db->or_where(array('ot.status' => 'completed'));
    $this->db->group_end();
    $this->db->where('ot.buyer_completed', 'no');
    $this->db->where("ot.refunded_date BETWEEN '{$date_from}' AND '{$date_to}'");
    $this->db->group_by('mt.id');
    $query  = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

and i am handling it in VIEW like this.

```
<?php
              $i = 0;
              $grandcomm = 0;
              $grandrefcomm = 0;
              $grandtotal = 0;
              foreach ($orders as $order) {
                $i++;

                $referral_name = get_userrow($order['buyer_id'])->referral_name;
                if ($referral_name) {
                  $refferals_who_place_orders = get_userrowbyrefemail($referral_name)->id;
                  $ref_orders = get_ref_total_orders($refferals_who_place_orders, $date_from, $date_to);
                  $ref_commision = $ref_orders * 50;
                }
              ?>
                <tr>
                  <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                  <td><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/Members/view/<?php echo $order['buyer_id']; ?>"><?php echo get_userrow($order['buyer_id'])->first_name . ' ' . get_userrow($order['buyer_id'])->last_name; ?></a></td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success"><?php echo $order['buyer_id']; ?></span></td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success"><?php echo $order['bank_account_title']; ?></span></td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success"><?php echo $order['account_number']; ?></span></td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success"><?php echo $order['bank_name']; ?></span></td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success"><?php echo $order['mobile_number']; ?></span></td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success"><?php echo $order['totalorders']; ?></span></td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success"><?php echo $ref_orders; ?></span></td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success"><?php echo $ref_commision; ?></span></td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success"><?php echo number_format($order['totalcomm'], 0); ?></span></td>
                  <td><span class="label label-success"><?php echo number_format($order['totalcomm'] + $ref_commision, 0); ?></span></td>
```

```
<?php
                    $grandcomm += $order['totalcomm'];
                    $grandrefcomm += $ref_commision;
                    $grandtotal += $order['totalcomm'] + $ref_commision;
                  }
                  ?>
```

Now this function working correctly get all the marketers commission who placed order. In following picture we can see the **marketer 628** commission.

**Problem**

According to my function I am not getting the name of *marketer 474* because he did not place any order. Now question is that how can I get the name of *marketer 474* in my list because his referee placed 4 orders.

[image]

So for example if commission of one order is 50 then total commission is 50*4 = 200. 200 commission of Referrer.

**Now anyone can guide me how can I update my function so that i get name and count commission of the marketers who did not place any order but his referee placed order?**

Comment: Please do not add [tag:mysqli]. I have already removed it once. There's no mysqli in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have records on `tableA` that may not have pairs on `tableB` you must to use LEFT JOIN.

On your query you select records from table `orders` and join with table `members`, but you must to do it on reverse order to archive de result you want using left join.

you can change the code bellow:

```
$this->db->from('orders ot');
$this->db->join('members mt', 'mt.id = ot.buyer_id');
```

to:

```
$this->db->from('members mt');
$this->db->join('orders ot', 'mt.id = ot.buyer_id', 'left');
```

This is produce a list of all members which may or may not has orders

Comment: I think this give same results

Comment: you are right, he must to move the where clause to join or put 'OR ot.id is null'